# How to import CSV column? Import-Csv not working as planned

Tags: powershell, csv, windows-7

I have a drop down list that's being populated by a CSV file. There are many columns in the CSV, but it only pulls from the `Name` column. Here's what I have that works just fine in most Win 7, and all Win 8+ PC's I've tried it on.

```
$customers = Import-CSV "$dir\Apps\customers.csv"
$List = $customers.name | Sort-Object
```

After that there's a `ForEach` loop to put each item from the list into the menu.

Lately I've been noticing an issue on a couple Win 7 PC's that I can't figure out. The import option doesn't work unless I specify all the headers with the `-Header` option. I get this error:

[image]

After getting it to import correctly by adding all the headers I can't get it to save `$customers.name` into the `$List` variable, with or without the sorting. However, if I provide an index number (ex `$customers[2].name`) it works.

To work around this I've looked at ways to measure the number of rows in the CSV by using the following options after `$customers`:

```
$csvlength = Get-Content "$dir\Apps\customers.csv" | Measure-Object - lines
```

or

```
$csvlength = Import-CSV "$dir\Apps\customers.csv" | Measure-Object
```

From there I can see the length by looking at `$csvlength.lines` or `$csvlength.count`.

Is there a way to use that information to save the list of names into `$List`? I've tried something like this with no success:

```
$List = $customers[0-$csvlength.count] | Sort-Object
```

Also, I've noticed that when importing the headers it includes `Name` in the list. If at all possible I'd like to not include the header. I also have a line at the end of the CSV that has other info in it, but no name. That shows up as a blank line. If possible I'd like that to be removed as well.

Comment: What powershell version are you using? I ask because I think WIndows 7 still included Powershell 2.0 to beign with, and then there was an update you could install to get Powershell 3.0. The difference between 2.0 and 3.0 would cause some of the problems you've described.

Comment: I'm going to say 2.0. This is a script to help setup new PCs out of the box so it would have to work without any windows or powershell updates. I've ran this script on other (already in production) win 7 PCs, and even some win xp, and the drop down works. Could be that those were up to date though. Right now I'm testing it on a PC where I just installed a fresh copy of 7.

Comment: Yeah ok. In PowerShell 2.0, you either need to do $customers[2].name or you could do a foreach loop, something like (foreach($c in $customers){ $c.name }

It wasn't until 3.0 that you could do $customers.Name and expect it to iterate automatically for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell v2 `$array.Foo` only allows access to a property `Foo` of the array object itself, not to a property `Foo` of the array *elements*. Allowing access to element properties via the array variable is one of the major changes that was introduced with PowerShell v3.

To work around this limitiation in v2 you need to expand the property before sorting:

```
$List = $customers | Select-Object -Expand name | Sort-Object
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked for the drop down list. Except now autocomplete doesn't work and when I click "Go" nothing happens... I'll play with it and post another question if needed.

Comment: Please do not move the target. If you have a new question: post a new question.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the help. I got it to work again except for the autocomplete.